# How to append a div with a new div and put var inside that new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am getting data from a XML and displaying it, but if I append another div with a var inside a new div, I get `[object Object]` instead of the XML data. How can I append a div with a new div plus var inside, this is what im trying to do

```
$('#channels').append('<div id="logo">'+$(this).find("display-name")+'</div>');
```

below is the full code im using

```
<div class="channels" id="channels"></div>

var xml = "<tv generator-info-name='tvchannels' source-info-name='tvchannels'><channel id='1234'><display-name>Channel 1</display-name></channel><channel id='5678'><display-name>Channel 2</display-name></channel><channel id='543553'><display-name>Channel 3</display-name></channel><channel id='324324'><display-name>Channel 4</display-name></channel></tv>",

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc );

$xml.find('channel').each(function (i,e) {

  $('#channels').append('<div id="logo">'+$(this).find("display-name")+'</div>');

});
```

Comment: What is `find("display-name")` is `display-name` is class?

Comment: its the XML data name

Comment: .find() getting back an object- to solve you most use .find().text() or something like that

Answer (score 2):

`$(...).find()` yields a jQuery object which serializes to `[object Object]`. You wanted to get the text instead; use `text()` method on the objects for that:

```js
var xml = "<tv generator-info-name='tvchannels' source-info-name='tvchannels'><channel id='1234'><display-name>Channel 1</display-name></channel><channel id='5678'><display-name>Channel 2</display-name></channel><channel id='543553'><display-name>Channel 3</display-name></channel><channel id='324324'><display-name>Channel 4</display-name></channel></tv>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc);

$xml.find('channel').each(function(i, e) {
  $('#channels').append('<div id="logo">' + $(this).find("display-name").text() + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="channels" id="channels"></div>
```